# Robinhood - should I expect to receive a tax document?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, dividends, robinhood

I started investing last year with a small amount so my dividend  earnings for 2020 is only about $5. Robinhood says that my tax document should be available on or before Feb 16. Should I expect to get a tax document from them for such a small amount?

I contacted them via email but haven't received any response yet. If I am not going to receive a tax document then I won't have to wait until Feb 16 to file my taxes.

Answer (score 3):

From a [Robinhood FAQ](https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/common-tax-questions/#:%7E:text=You%27ll%20only%20receive%20a,will%20not%20receive%20a%201099.)

> You’ll only receive a 1099 tax document from Robinhood if the proceeds
> from dividends exceed $10, the value of referral stock grants exceed
> $600, or you sell a position. If you don’t meet any of these criteria,
> you will not receive a 1099.

So, the minimum is $10 in dividends, but you can still get a 1099 if your dividends were less and you meet one of the other requirements. These are pretty much universal among brokers.

*Regardless of whether you receive a 1099-DIV form from RobinHood (or anyone else) or not (on the grounds that the amount is less than $10),* **you should report *all* dividend income to the IRS on your tax return, and all the dividend income gets reported in the same place (which is *not* under "Other Income").**  Remember that when you sign your tax return, you are affirming under penalty of perjury that you have declared all your income on the tax return.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth adding to your answer a reminder to the OP that regardless of whether he receives a 1099 from RobinHood to or not, those $5 dividend earnings are income to the OP and must be reported on the 1040 form.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the info. So even if I have not cashed out the dividends into my bank account (I don't even know if this is possible or not as I only see a message in Robinhood app that since I have x shares of y, I earned $z divident), I will report that while filing my 2020 taxes.

Comment: @Tan Yes, even if you keep the cash sitting in your investment account (or it is even re-invested automatically with DRIP) you need to report it. I do not use Robinhood so I am not familiar on whether they offer DRIP or how they handle cash.

Comment: I am wondering if should I report it under 1099 INT section or somewhere else?

Comment: @Tan Dividends are reported with a 1099-DIV form. I don't know the exact section where you report it on your tax return, but it's usually described as "other income" (as in, not directly earned from a paycheck).

Comment: I got an email from them today saying the following `Well, good news! You won’t need any 1099 forms from Robinhood this year, so you don’t need to wait on us to start filing your taxes.` So I don't need to report anything then I believe.

Comment: @Tan You have drawn exactly the wrong conclusion from what this answer is trying to tell you.